# Install mysql2 extension for ruby on rails with 64 bits ruby and 64 bits windows

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, 64-bit

I've installed the 64bit version of ruby from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

Trying to install mysql, i downloaded the 64bit version of the connector

and i get the error

```
compiling client.c
In file included from client.c:1:0:
./mysql2_ext.h:17:19: fatal error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [client.o] Error 1
```

as you can see in the next screen

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end [this faq](https://gist.github.com/remomueller/5027829) worked. I guess because i downloaded [exactly the version of the connector linked](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=377980) in the article and run

```
gem install mysql2 --no-ri --no-rdoc --platform=ruby -- --with-mysql-include=C:/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-winx64\include --with-mysql-lib=C:/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-winx64\lib
```

EDIT - the correct version to use of the connector for 64 bit version is [found here](https://copy.com/CHZ4eT4us6f1). The normal version segfaults, so thanks to this thread i found the correct version https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/372